# Run query on query results

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to clean all duplicate results on a phonebook i have, that means i'm trying to compare landline1 to landline2 and if they are equal (but not empty) i would like to either NULL or just replace with empty string one of them.

i use the following line to list all the matching results:

```
SELECT * FROM `csv_confirmed` WHERE landline1=landline2 AND landline1!="";
```

which gives me a full list, but it's too many to edit manually and i'm trying to automate it.

What would be the easiest way to run `UPDATE` (or anything else that might work here) to clear the "landline2" column of the results i found ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your query to an update:

```
UPDATE csv_confirmed
SET landline2 = NULL
WHERE landline1=landline2 AND landline1!=""
```